# find neighbour in 2d array based on probability given by normal distribution

Tags: arrays

I have a quadratic 2D-array representing my world. Each cell can be empty or populated by a player.
I want to pick one player at random and let him interact with another player.
The second player should be picked based on a 2d normal distribution probability, that means the closer the cell the more likely it should be to be chosen, array borders should be wrapped.

So I´m searching for a function that takes as argument the array, x and y coordinates of player 1 and the standard deviation of the normal distribution (σx = σy). It should return x and y coordinates of player 2.

additionally, players can spawn new players, the location of the new player should be found by the same method described above, but this time the function should return x and y of an empty cell.

Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx Mike of SST for aiding my thoughts, Box-Muller Transform put me on the right track for finding the polar method.

The following algorithm does the trick:

```
class Program
{
    static Random rnd = new Random();

    static void Neighbour(uint sx, uint sy, uint x, uint y, double std, out uint nx, out uint ny)
    {
        double u, v, q, p;
        do
        {
            u = rnd.NextDouble() * 2 - 1;
            v = rnd.NextDouble() * 2 - 1;
            q = u * u + v * v;
        } while (q == 0.0 || q >= 1.0);

        p = Math.Sqrt(-2 * Math.Log(q) / q) * std;

        nx = (uint)((Math.Round(u * p) % sx) + sx + x) % sx;
        ny = (uint)((Math.Round(v * p) % sy) + sy + y) % sy;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const uint SX = 25;
        const uint SY = 35;

        const uint X = 7;
        const uint Y = 5;

        const double std = 4;

        uint nx, ny;

        const uint N = 100000;

        uint[,] arr = new uint[SY, SX];

        for (uint i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            Neighbour(SX, SY, X, Y, std, out nx, out ny);
            arr[ny, nx]++;
        }

        for (uint iy = 0; iy < SY; iy++)
        {
            for (uint ix = 0; ix < SX; ix++)
                Console.Write(arr[iy, ix].ToString().PadLeft(4));
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

    }
}
```

I can call Neighbour in a loop until I find coordinates different from Player 1 coordinates and inhabited/uninhabited depending on purpose.

[image: # of times cell beeing chosen]

Answer (score 1):

You could create a secondary array of player co-ordinates, ordered by the magnitude of their distance from Player 1.  Generate a random number, according to your distribution function, which is an index into the secondary array.  Either ignore the result if it is Player 1 or exclude Player 1 from the secondary array when it is generated.

```
1) Create secondary array of x & y co-ordinate tuples.
2) For each element in primary array
    If element is not empty and element does not contain player 1
        add co-ordinates of the element to the secondary array
3) Sort secondary array by distance from player 1
    Where distance is the square root of 
    ((difference between player 1 x-coord and element x-coord) squared +
     (difference between player 1 y-coord and element y-coord) squared)
    And the difference is the greater minus the lesser 
        (since sign does not matter as it is being squared anyway).
4) Generate index into secondary array according to the distribution function.
5) Return the x and y coordinates from the element in the secondary array.
```

You can use the [Box-Muller Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) to generate the index according to a standard distribution.

New players would be inserted into the secondary array (assuming it's implemented as a dynamically sized list, or similar) in the sorted position.